# In python, how can I do a non-blocking system call?

Tags: python

In Python, is it possible to do a non-blocking system call without forking off a thread?  i.e., can I avoid:

```
import thread
thread.start_new_thread(os.system,('cmd',))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module (Popen) and have the result written to a file.  You can either "wait" for the subprocess to terminate or proceed with other business and poll for the result in the file etc.