# how do I make a fork or non-blocking system call in python

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, autokey

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path) but with a different take.

In Ubuntu, I use Autokey, which uses python to automate keystrokes it observes. So I have `<super>+e` mapped to open Gedit, `<shift>+<super>+3` to open OOwriter, etc etc. When I make one of these calls, I cannot make another one until the previous program called has exited.

Here's a sample of the script it executes:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("/opt/openoffice.org3/program/scalc")
```

... same behavior using:

```
import os
os.system("/opt/openoffice.org3/program/scalc")
```

This all worked smoothly in my previous Ubuntu 10.04LTS, but things have changed since then and I can't repeated make these calls.

**Would you please help me with how to fork or do something to "get back" from that subprocess.call() without waiting for the program to exit?** I tried nohup and backgrounding `/opt/openoffice.org3/program/scalc &` but those do nothing (probably breaks something in Autokey and Py)

---

**Answer:** the answer below didn't actually work, but got me snooping around more and I found another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613713/in-python-how-can-i-do-a-non-blocking-system-call) which did work for my situation!

```
#Enter script code -- mapped to <super>+e
import thread
thread.start_new_thread(os.system,('gedit',))
```

This totally worked!! I can hit `<super>+e` 2 or 3 times in a row and it keeps adding tabs to gedit. :) This script makes Autokey act as though the command in quotes is typed at the command line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's as easy as using `Popen` instead of `call`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("/opt/openoffice.org3/program/scalc")
```

`call` should never have worked that way since it has to return the exit code, meaning the program would actually have to exit.